# Creating a basic list box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How can I get a basic select list box working.

This is what I have

```
= f.select :similar_level, @similar_levels, html_options: { size: 5 }, size: 5, input_html: { size: 5 }
```

This is what I want

```
<select size=5>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I cant seem to get the size part working. I am using v2.1.0

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cant seem to get the size part working"? What are you expecting and what are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= f.select :similar_level, @similar_levels, {}, { :size => '5' }
```